# Compare a date with a block of dates in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, date-comparison

i tried to ready a lot of date comparisons that i found here on stackoverflow and spread into the internet but i wasn't able to find the solution.

I have the following table (Trips):

```
VehicleID   DriverID   xID   CheckIn   CheckOut   DateHour
      462        257     7         1          0   16/12/2017 20:40:00
      462        257     7         0          1   19/12/2017 10:05:00
     5032       3746    11         1          0   02/10/2017 07:00:00
     5032       3746    11         0          1   06/10/2017 17:00:00
```

When my company receives a traffic ticket, i want to compare the date from the ticket with the hole block of dates from the table "Trips", each block starts with CheckIn = 1 and finishes with CheckOut = 1, so this way i will know which driver was responsable for the ticket through the DriverID.

For example: the traffic ticket date and time are: `17/12/2017 08:00:00` and the Vehicle is the one with id = 462, i'll insert this date and time in a field in our system to consult automaticaly which driver was driving that car at that moment, we won´t use the ticket table yet. Looking at my example, i know it should return DriverID = 257, but theres a lot of trips with the same vehicle and diferent drivers.....The major problem is how can i compare the Date and Hour from the Ticket with the range of dates from the trips, since i have to consider 1 trip = 2 lines in the table

Unfortunately i can't change the way this table was created, cause we need this 2 lines, CheckIn and CheckOut, separately.

Any thoughts or directions?

Thank you for your attention

Comment: What are you trying to compare exactly? ie, are you trying to list all the trips that had the same date as the ticket? What columns are in the ticket table? You should get an answer pretty quickly but we'll need a little more info first
Edit: More likely you're trying to find the In/Out rows where the ticket date falls in that range?

Comment: Is xID unique for each trip? I figure VehicleID and DriverID are probably not

Comment: For example: the traffic ticket date and time are: 17/12/2017 08:00:00 and the Vehicle is the one with id = 462, i'll insert this date and time in a field in our system to consult automaticaly which driver was driving that car at that moment, we won´t use the ticket table yet. Looking at my example, i know it should return DriverID = 257, but theres a lot of trips with the same vehicle and diferent drivers.....The major problem is how can i compare the Date and Hour from the Ticket with the range of dates from the trips, since i have to consider 1 trip = 2 lines in the table.

Comment: Good info. Add it to your question at the bottom, in an edit. It'll disappear here eventually.

Comment: You'll need to select the dates greater, and then out of those (subquery) select the dates that are less. Then you'll know if it's in the range or not. I'll post something shortly.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and DBMS products differ very much in their support for DATEs). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.VehicleID 
  ,t1.DriverID 
  ,t1.xID
  ,t1.DateHour as Checkin
  ,t2.DateHour as Checkout
from trips as t1 join trips as t2 --self join trips to get both start and end in a single row
  on t1.VehicleID = t2.VehicleID -- add all columns 
 and t1.DriverID = t2.DriverID   -- which define 
 and t1.xID = t2.xID             -- a unique trip
 and t1.Checkin  = 1 -- start
 and t2.Checkout = 1 -- end
join tickets -- now join tickets 
  on tickets.trafficDateHour between t1.DateHour and t2.DateHour
```

Comment: Thank you dnoeth i will try your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't make sample tables, this will not run as is, but something like this should do it for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM tickets, trips
WHERE
trips.datehour in (
    SELECT trips.datehour  
    FROM tickets, trips
    WHERE
        tickets.ticket_date < trips.datehour AND
        trips.checkin = 0
) AND
tickets.ticket_date > trips.datehour AND
trips.checkin = 1
```

If you are running this for a specific date as described in the comment above, it will work. If you are trying to run it for a set of ticket dates all at once, you'll require recursion. Recursion is a different beast depending on your flavor of SQL.

Comment: Thank you, i will try to use at the project. I'll post later the results.